# how to solve that error in android studio?

Tags: android, android-resources

I am facing this problem when I've added dependencies.

**Error:**

> AAPT2 error: check logs for details

and another problem failed linking file resources

> build failed  2s 780ms
>   Run build   2s 504ms
>   Load build  9ms
>   Configure build 217ms
>   Calculate task graph    226ms
>   Run tasks   2s 46ms
>   null
>   C:/Users/MOON COMP&MOBILE/AndroidStudioProjects/ParentalControl2
>   app/src/main/res
>   layout/activity_login.xml
>   layout/activity_rgistration.xml 
>   null
>   failed linking file resources.

Comment: Go through all your XML files and resolve errors, then clean or rebuild the project from the build menu

Start with your most recent edited XML file

Comment: No it is not working Bro

Comment: Are you sure with your XMLs? Try adding those XMLs in question. Most of the time it's XML issue as the error is failed linking file resources.

Comment: maybe there is issue in drawable file in resource check by using following steps.
goto Gradle-app-Tasks-build-assembleDebug- after double click on this you can find error in run window.

Comment: how does it relate to `javascript`?

Answer (score 0):

it reads:

> layout/activity_login.xml
>
> layout/activity_rgistration.xml **null**

check these XML resources for *spelling errors* and things marked red.